# PHP Unset is resetting my Session Array

Tags: php, mysql, session, unset

I am encountering an issue where i am sending a request to delete a specific product out of a session array. When the results return the session is null and it clearly has more than one value in it when resetting. Here is the code.

```
    if (in_array($input_product_to_delete, $_SESSION['cart_items'])) {
        var_dump($_SESSION['cart_items']);
        var_dump($input_product_to_delete);
        unset($_SESSION['cart_items'],$input_product_to_delete);
        var_dump($_SESSION['cart_items']);
    }
```

The conditional is being entered and clears the entire session when i need it to just clear the one object.
Here is the output from the dumps.

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(12) {
        [0]=> string(1) "4"
        ["ID"]=> string(1) "4"
        [1]=> string(11) "Razor Mouse"
        ["name"]=> string(11) "Razor Mouse"
        [2]=> string(46) "Lights Up with customizable keyboard shortcuts"
        ["description"]=> string(46) "Lights Up with customizable keyboard shortcuts"
        [3]=> string(2) "65"
        ["quantity"]=> string(2) "65"
        [4]=> string(5) "29.99"
        ["price"]=> string(5) "29.99"
        [5]=> string(8) "Hardware"
        ["type"]=> string(8) "Hardware"
    }
    [1]=> array(12) {
        [0]=> string(1) "5"
        ["ID"]=> string(1) "5"
        [1]=> string(13) "Nvidia GTX970"
        ["name"]=> string(13) "Nvidia GTX970"
        [2]=> string(70) "Extremely powerful graphics card for games that are graphics intensive"
        ["description"]=> string(70) "Extremely powerful graphics card for games that are graphics intensive"
        [3]=> string(2) "20"
        ["quantity"]=> string(2) "20"
        [4]=> string(6) "525.99"
        ["price"]=> string(6) "525.99"
        [5]=> string(8) "Hardware"
        ["type"]=> string(8) "Hardware"
    }
    [2]=> array(12) {
        [0]=> string(1) "9"
        ["ID"]=> string(1) "9"
        [1]=> string(4) "tewt"
        ["name"]=> string(4) "tewt"
        [2]=> string(4) "test"
        ["description"]=> string(4) "test"
        [3]=> string(3) "123"
        ["quantity"]=> string(3) "123"
        [4]=> string(1) "2"
        ["price"]=> string(1) "2"
        [5]=> string(8) "Hardware"
        ["type"]=> string(8) "Hardware"
    }
}

array(12) {
        [0]=> string(1) "9"
        ["ID"]=> string(1) "9"
        [1]=> string(4) "tewt"
        ["name"]=> string(4) "tewt"
        [2]=> string(4) "test"
        ["description"]=> string(4) "test"
        [3]=> string(3) "123"
        ["quantity"]=> string(3) "123"
        [4]=> string(1) "2"
        ["price"]=> string(1) "2"
        [5]=> string(8) "Hardware"
        ["type"]=> string(8) "Hardware"
    }

NULL
```

The session is null after the unset.

Comment: `unset($_SESSION['cart_items'],$input_product_to_delete);` will unset `$_SESSION['cart_items']` && `$input_product_to_delete` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php. If you want to only unset `$input_product_to_delete` in `$_SESSION['cart_items']` you will need to specify it `unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$input_product_to_delete]);`

Comment: Oh wow, I might of added a comma not realizing what it did. I just came to php thank you for the explanation. I had previous examples of using unset just did not recognize that comma. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a very simple problem. **Unset** takes many parameters you want. But with a comma separated you delete all of them. In your case you delete both variables.

`$_SESSION['cart_items']` and `$input_product_to_delete`

So if you want to delete an element of your array you have to set them as array array for example:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$input_product_to_delete])
```

i hope that solve your problem.

Comment: Not quite sure why im recieving Illegal offset type in unset. But i will troubleshoot that one.

Comment: Check your variable with isset before.

Comment: The reason was because $input_product_to_delete is an object and you can't access an array's index with an object. i fixed the issue doing  foreach ($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $key => $value)
  {
   if ($value['name'] == $input_product_to_delete['name']) {
    unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$key]);
   }
  }